# Session.getActiveUserLocale() not set language

Tags: google-apps-script, internationalization

I am setting my Google products language as Turkish you can see the screenshot [image: language_setting_page] but `Session.getActiveUserLocale()` return "en".

Do you have any idea?

Comment: How are using Session.getActiveUserLocale() and how are you calling the the script that contains it?

Comment: Same problem here for pt_BR